# Changing user input in real time using the cmd module

Tags: python, windows

I would like to be able to change characters as the user types text into a (cmd.Cmd) prompt using the cmd python module. So when a user types in a character I would like to be able to process that character and change it in line. Is there a way to use the cmd module to process and replace every character as it is typed or is there another module that I should be using?

edit: This is for running in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are searching to hook keyboard strokes on windows using python. if i am not mistaken in my assumption, hooking is not trivial on python since dll is required.

you may try [pyHook](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/developer.shtml), it uses Windows API to do the job.

Here is the [API](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/doc/pyhook/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this with `cmd.Cmd` either but it would be possible with `curses` - see [Curses Programming with Python](http://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/curses.html). The `getch()` function will return the keycode but not echo it unless `curses` has been told to `echo()` it. That would let you take the keycode and transform it however you liked (e.g. into an 'X' to hide the characters entered as a password) before displaying the character(s) on the screen.

Alternatively, though I haven't used it, the [Console module](http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm) seems to provide equivalent functionality for Python on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am writing a Windows app and _Curses_ seems to only run in a UNIX/LINUX environment. The _Curses_ docs reference a similar Windows command line tool [here](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm), but the latest release is for XP and is of course only 32-bit. I am editing my question to reflect the Windows aspect of the problem.